# IE BHO: distinguish between JavaScript object and function

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, atl, bho

I am developing a BHO for Internet Explorer. In the BHO code, when I enumerate through properties of a JavaScript object, I need to detect whether property value is a JavaScript function.

I enumerate object properties, and get each property value as a `VARIANT`, like this:

```cpp
CComQIPtr<IDispatchEx> pObj = /* ... get a reference to JavaScript object */
DISPID dispId = DISPID_STARTENUM;

for (; pObj && NOERROR == pObj->GetNextDispID(fdexEnumDefault, dispId, &dispId);)
{
    DISPPARAMS dispParams = { 0 };
    CComVariant value; // here I get property value 

    // invoke property getter
    pObj->Invoke(dispId, IID_NULL, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, &dispParams, &value, NULL, NULL);

    // determine value kind
    switch (value.vt)
    {
    case VT_DISPATCH:
        // both Object and Function get here...
    }
}
```

Both for objects and functions, the `VARTYPE vt` equals `VT_DISPATCH`. I'm looking for a way to distinguish between the two.

#### Just a side note

In JavaScript, I can do:

```js
typeof obj === "function"
```

or

```js
Object.getPrototypeOf(obj).constructor.name === "function"
```

(though in IE, `constructor.name` is `undefined`).

Comment: probably IDispatch::GetTypeInfo... at worst you write a one argument function to return the parameter's type and run it via window.eval